Movie about a couple who find a young woman and let her stay with them
I remember I watched the trailer of a movie 2 years ago.
The movie was about a couple who find a young woman who doesn't have a place to stay and let her stay with them. After a couple of days they start having problems because of her. The husband starts having dreams about being with her. He even dreams about having sex with her while his wife is asleep in the same bed. 
Then I think the girl possibly dies or fakes her death.

Do you remeber what genre was? It seems trhiller or similar, but i you remeber it i would be easy

If the girl tries to kill the husband and kills or injures the wife, then I'd say it is Poison Ivy too.

When you say you saw the trailer 2 years ago, do you mean that it was a new movie 2 years ago? Like you saw the trailer in a theater?

Is it possibly Poison Ivy with Tom Skerritt and Drew Barrymore?
Poison Ivy (Trailer) - Drew Barrymore

A seductive teen befriends an introverted high school student and schemes her way into the lives of her wealthy family. ~ imdb

Here's the others in the series though I think only the 3rd would apply to what you remember.
Poison Ivy 2 - Lily (Trailer) - Alyssa Milano
Poison Ivy 3 - The New Seduction (Trailer) - Jaimie Pressly
Poison Ivy 4 - The Secret Society (Trailer) - female lead schemes her way into a school clique, not a family.
There's also The Hand That Rocks The Cradle from 1992. I recall it has a similar theme to the 1st Poison Ivy.
The Hand That Rocks The Cradle (Trailer)
And also, if your memories aren't exact, check into American Beauty with Kevin Spacey.

You might want to elaborate in which way this fits the details from the question in order to flesh out the answer a little more.

It also could have been one of the sequels. Maybe Poison Ivy: The New Seduction. Although those came out way more than two years ago.

Er, I don't think posting multiple suggestions is wrong per se, but 6 might be a bit too much...

It might not be necessary to separate all the varios Poison Ivy sequels into their own answers, especially since they're probably largely the same and hard to distinguish given the details from the question. But the last two suggestions are quite different and should be posted as their own answers individually, to be assessed, voted on and accepted each on their own merits. (Preferrably with some elaborations in which way they fit to the question's details at all, rather than just throwing a bunch of titles onto the question and seeing which sticks.)

Was just throwing out some titles to see if any jogged the memory, I didn't think the alternate guesses were good enough to warrant their own answer and probably didn't feel like spamming with multiple answers. I generally do this then come back and edit it all once feedback has been made by the OP or others, but there doesn't seem to have been any in this case and so it was forgotten about.

Possible "Nobody Walks", Starring John Krasinski and Olivia Thirlby.

Could be Thy Neighbor's Wife (2001)

A scorned woman plots revenge for her husband’s suicide by integrating herself as a housekeeper for a dysfunctional Beverly Hills family to first alienate, and then emotionally and physically destroy them.




